# How to call Environment Variables from Azure Devops Variable Groups in Terraform files?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

Vairables are declared in Terraform files. Environment Variables are declared in Azure DevOps as TF_VAR_example. Still when the Pipeline runs it gets stuck in terraform plan, waiting for an input for that value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define them in the env section of your tasks:

```
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'TF_plan'
    env:
      TF_VAR_example: $(TF_VAR_example)
```